# How to free subarray's mem which is part of bigger array

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have some trouble with dynamic memory deletion. I have array of 100 integers, but later in runtime more than the half of the array is not used, so i want to free that memory. Here is my attempt. Can anybody explain why i get an error? Thanks!

```
void dynSybarrDel(){
    int* intArr = new int[100];
    int* subArr = (intArr + 50);
    delete subArr;
}
```

Comment: That's not possible. You must `delete[]` what you `new[]` (and you don't use `delete[]` so you have *two* errors). What is the *actual* problem you try to solve this way? Why do you want to "free subarray"?

Comment: I have a class representing inventory and lots of items are being removed every moment, but not so many are being added, so i wanted to optimize the memory usage. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: So you need a [*container*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) that can expand some, but mostly shrink? Start with the "default" container [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), and see if that's enough for your needs. You can change its size (number of elements in the vector) and capacity (allocated memory) separately as you see fit. And then I recommend you simply *forget* to optimize for space unless you're targeting a limited system. Optimizations, for space or performance, should be the *last* thing you do. And only if you really need it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

However if you malloc the memory, you could remove to the end with realloc:

```
#include  <cstring>
void dynSybarrDel(){
    int* intArr = (int*)malloc(100 * sizeof(int));
    int* subArr = (intArr + 50);
    intArr = realloc(intArr, (subArr - intArr)*sizeof(int));
};
```

### Edit

To initialize an array-element of specific type in `malloc`ated memory just do this (however you needn't do this on int or other builtin types, when you know that it is overwritten before read, else there would be random values):

```
new(elementPtr) myType("parameter1", 2.0);
```

And to destroy:

```
elementPtr->~myType();
```

`elementPtr` is just the adress of an element by iteration like this:

```
MyType* elementPtr = myArr;
for(int i = arrSize; i; --i, ++elementPtr)
```

---

However if you can use `std::vector` it allows you more things to do:

```
#include <vector>

void dynSybarrDel(){
    std::vector<int> intArr(100);
    auto subArr = intArr.begin() + 50;
    intArr.erase(subArr, intArr.end());
};
```

You could even remove a part inside the vector:

```
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> intArr(10);
    std::iota(intArr.begin(), intArr.end(), 0); // linear counting [0, 10)

    for(int i: intArr) {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    };
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    auto eraseMeBegin = intArr.begin() + 3;
    auto eraseMeEnd   = intArr.end() - 2;

    intArr.erase(eraseMeBegin, eraseMeEnd);

    for(int i: intArr) {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    };
    std::cout << '\n';
};
```

Produced output:

> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
>
> 0 1 2 8 9

Comment: Thank you! This is what i was looking for!

Comment: `realloc` is dangerous with non-trivial types, since it may copy the data into a new buffer. Also, `(int)subArr - (int)intArr` is an unsafe way to compute the size of the buffer.

Comment: And just regular subtraction should work; there’s no need to convert to `int`s first anyway.

Comment: Some stl-implementations just use pointers in their iterators, others include a reference to the container and an offset (slower), it doesn't matter if you put it in a struct or just doing the operations directly. If the stl-user fails, using the types correctly, it would always be an security-issue.

Comment: @DanielH: Regular subtraction isn't quite enough, since the result will be missing a factor of the element size.

Comment: @user2357112 vector also uses realloc on the base level in most stl-implementations. And I do not know, what could be dangerous, when eg. an array of std::string is moved around. If you write some dangerous code in which the this-pointer inside a member-function is stored elsewere, which would be really dangerous with std::vectors... There could be two solutions, use unique_ptr<T> or just update the offset with a member-function when reallocated.

Comment: @DanielH I use the cast to int, because it should be the raw offset of both pointers and otherwise you can think it is the difference of int-elements between both pointers, which lead to too small size of the reallocated buffer. I will improve it to look more natural and to work on all platforms (however size_t should work on all)...

Comment: @cmdLP: `std::vector` implementations only use `realloc` if they can determine that it's safe to do so; implementations that use `realloc` for all types are non-conforming. As for the unsafety of this code, besides the potential `realloc` issues with nontrivial types, casting pointers to `int` can overflow. (On weird architectures, I think it's also possible for the difference to be wrong even without overflow.)

Comment: @user2357115 If simple pointerarithmetic doesn't work on such _weird_ architectures, the most stl-code has problems itsself, can you give examples for such architectures?

Comment: @cmdLP I don’t know if you meant to address a deleted comment or if you typoed the username of the previous commenter. If the latter, then I doubt the standard library relies on pointer-to-int casting. Three of the four data models described [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Data_models) don’t let it work properly, including the ones in common use for 64-bit systems today. That’s what `uintptr_t` is for.

Answer (score -1):

this code here:   `int* intArr = new int[100];` tells the compiler give a memory space of 4*100. you basically allocate it to your own use- and no one can use it beside your program until it goes back to the memory pool.

since the compiler already did what you told him to do (and gave you the memory). you can't ask from him to ignore it on runtime.
however, you can ask for half the space and allocate new memory later on your program.

when reallocating new memory the compiler first try to see if the extension of your current memory is  free and in the right size for you. if so, it gives you the address  of the continuation of your current array, if not' it copies your current array to another memory address with enough space (if possible).